# How to measure the Aircraft cabin air quality?

Tags: cabin-design, air-quality

Is there any tool or mechanism to do quantitative analysis of aircraft cabin/cockpit air quality?

Answer (score 2):

A few years ago, the Australian Civil Aviation Safety Authority convened an  [Expert Panel on Aircraft Air Quality](http://www.casa.gov.au/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD::pc=PC_90041).

From page 138 of the report they discuss the available monitoring devices. From my brief readthrough, there were no real monitoring devices for this purpose at the time (2009) however research was being conducted.

Comment: its specifically for the Bleed air contamination but if we have some other ways which have contaminated the Cabin air quality either CO, or if some passenger is able to get some liquid poisonous gas in the permissible limits of less than 100ml.